# How to open the trade route to Britain?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

So in the mini-game 'Kenways Fleet' you can dispatch your fleet across the Atlantic to trade. Doing certain missions opens up access to new places to visit.

Which mission will unlock the trade routes to Britain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open the route to Britain, you have to do a mission called "Door to Europe" in Kenway's Fleet. It is part of the South African route. It will unlock "Bristol", which is located in Southern England.

[image: Screenshot of unlocking Bristol]

The other mission you need to do is called "Meet the Tributes I" in Kennway's Fleet. It is part of the Cape Verde Route. It will unlock London, the capital city of Great Britain.

[image: Screenshot of unlocking London]

Answer (score -3):

I can't say for sure exactly which one opens it up, but try all the trade routes going to the "old world". You only need to do each trade mission once. There aren't that many.